# Black Screen after password Unity not working

Tags: 14.04, password, startup

Hello this is my first question on here, but after looking around I cant seem to find a fix for my problem.

So here it is, Everytime I start up my PC I get the usual "enter Passcode" Which I do. But after this all I get is a black screen.

I already have the Ubuntu OS installed on my PC perfectly (well not so perfectly).
I cant seem to determine what the problem is, and sorry for the lack of any detail. If any is needed I am willing to oblige.

Comment: after reading through that question I believe my problem is with in the display or rather unity not working. does anyone know how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Unity isn't working reboot the machine, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

obtain dconf-tools with

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Next,

```
dconf dump /org/compiz/ > ~/Desktop/myCompizSettings
```

This will dump your Compiz Settings into a file on your Desktop for later review if needed.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

will reset compiz settings to default.

Finally,

```
setsid unity
```

The above command will restart Unity.

Return to the GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: I am not able to install dconf-tools, i get a bunch of errors when continuing with Y

Comment: If you told me what errors I could likely help you search for the answer to that which is already here.

Comment: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get or try with --fix-missing?                                                                this is at the bottom

Comment: What happens when you try with the --fix-missing switch?

Comment: I get a command not found, mind i can only use the recovery console.

Comment: What do you get with 'sudo apt-get check` ?

Comment: nothing that runs smoothly with zero errors

Comment: What happens if you boot normally, use the key combo CTRL-ALT-F1 to open a terminal and attempt the answer from there?

Comment: when I boot normally I can put in my password then blackscreen, at which point i get nothing no matter what. when I hit ctrl-alt-f1 at the password screen just before blackscreening I cant do anything in the terminal that does open.

Comment: does it prompt you to login when the terminal opens?

Comment: No, only when I boot normally or when I go into the recovery menu

Comment: So if you boot normally, and then login, you get a black screen, but CTRL-ALT-F1 opens a terminal without a login prompt????

Comment: I would say when I hit CTRL-ALT-F1 a black screen with the ability to type on it comes up, but thats it. its blank and nothing happens

Comment: It would appear there is more wrong here than just unity.

Comment: oh gosh, im thinking about just reinstalling the whole thing again

Comment: At this point I suggest you go back to http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it and review the section titled "An update or something else caused my problem"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Ubuntu is not installed correctly. You may use your disc (If you have one) OR your USB drive to install Ubuntu again. (You can use Lili to install Ubuntu on your USB drive) Before that, copy your files, because you may lose some of them.